# How to integrate a currency converter feature, by detecting country of user lives in

Tags: flutter, dart, currency, valueconverter

I'm trying to implement a feature where in

the app should detect the user's country then convert currency from `USD` to user's native currency.

i have completed the part of detecting user's location using location library.

but facing difficulties in checking user's native currency type  and then conversion of `USD` to that currency.

I have found a flutter package [`money2`](https://pub.dev/packages/money2) but was not clear.

Can someone guide me with it?

Thank you.